# Regarding Google Search Console report "Page Not Found"

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, 404

I am currently doing SEO through Google Search Console for a company website.

I am trying to solve website indexing issues, one of which is a 404 Error (page not found). While I do have the sitemap registered and uploaded to the GSC, Google's crawler crawls through pages that do not exist on the website at all. Because of that, I do not know what am I supposed to do about these pages which do not exist, yet are registered as if they somehow exist.

Has anybody else had this problem when indexing a website through Google Search Console? What is the best solution for this problem?

Please let me know in the comments. Thank you!

Comment: It may help to see examples of them. You can replace the domain name with example.com

Answer (score 1):

Goggle does not invent the urls. It is crawling them because it found links to them.

- Either on your website
- Or some other website.

The solution is to ensure there are no links within your website, to them. For external links, a 404 is a good result. You can tell Google to remove them. And it will in the next few days, only if it doesnt find any links to them.

If they have not disappeared,  you can disavow them.

Answer (score 1):

Not all 404 errors in GSC are caused by links from pages on your site.  If you click on the magnifying glass icon next to these 404 errors, AKA "Inspect URL", it will give you the source for the referring page.

Many times I find these 404 errors to actually be some spammy or hacked website that has an incorrect link or url.